# Is there a way to skip given files when performing a cleartool findmerge?

Tags: merge, clearcase, auto-generate

In our development environment, we have certain files that are autogenerated by some parsing tools, and they should never be merged from one branch to another.  We do have them under source control, however, so that only one user needs to run the generation tool for any given branch; all other users will get the generated files automatically.

Is there a way to tell "findmerge" to skip these files when it traverses the VOB?  If findmerge cannot resolve the differences in a file, it loads the default diff tool so the user can resolve the differences manually.  For these autogenerated files, this is a waste of time; the user just has to cancel it and then run the autogeneration tool when the findmerge is complete.

If it matters, we use dynamic views.

Comment: FYI we're using ClearCase version 7.1.2.1, cleartool version 7.1.2.5, VOB database schema version 54.

Comment: You're using a seriously ancient version of ClearCase that doesn't actually support any currently supported operating system. Have you looked into upgrading recently?

Comment: I'll find out.  We have hundreds of VOBs, probably thousands of branches and views. I don't know how much of an undertaking it would be to upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider the same approach as with [binary files](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/7.1.2?topic=operation-about-binary-files-in-deliver)

> Your project manager can overcome this problem by creating a special element type for the binary file type and specifying one of the following `mergetypes`:
>
> `never`: A merge or `findmerge` operation ignores versions whose element type has `never` as a `mergetype`.

So, as [in this page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/handling-binary-files-clearcase), something like:

> ```
> cleartool mkeltype -supertype file -mergetype never -nc FILE_NEVER_MERGE
> ```

And then, in the folder with your generated files (here for instance for XML files):

```
ct find path/to/generated -type f -ele "{eltype(xml)}" -exec "cleartool chtype -force FILE_NEVER_MERGE %CLEARCASE
```

Comment: The "never" merge type was added specifically for this use case. Also, if you use UCM, the auto generation could be done as part of a preop deliver-complete/rebase-complete trigger. That way you can ensure that the files generate CORRECTLY before allowing the operation to complete...

Comment: @VonC, thanks.  Our tools engineer is looking into this solution.

Comment: @livefree75 OK, let me know what they find.